# stackoverflow exception on multitasking console app

Tags: c#, .net, multitasking

I have a probram which runs some long algorithim, so I work it in many tasks.
while Job methods working in tasks I have another method which checking if all tasks done or if some still working. but JobChecker method gave me stackoverflow exception. why It gives error and how can I fix this?

```
public void Main()
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         string lineTemp = line;
         taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => Job(lineTemp, last)));
    }

    JobChecker(taskList);
}

public void JobChecker(List<Task> taskList)
{
    do
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    while (taskList.Any(x => x.Status == TaskStatus.Running));
}
```

Comment: Can you show the callstack.

Comment: What is `Job()` method and `last` variable?

Comment: @EZI Task.WaitAll solved my problem, please make it answer so I can accept. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of busy waiting, use the built-in functions like `Task.WaitAll` or  `Task.WhenAll`